# Split a data frame based on difference between values in different rows

Tags: r, split

I am not sure I am approaching this in the correct way, but what I am trying to do is split up a data frame into groups based on the difference between values.  For example, using the data below I would like to split on the difference between values in the MIN column, so if the difference is >2 then create a split, in the example below I would end up with 4 split sets of data.

```
MIN SEC PT  CO2R    CO2D    PAR
58  10  5   375.7   -11.6   1002
58  20  5   375.4   -11.6   1001
58  33  5   375.2   -11.6   1001
58  43  5   375.2   -11.5   1000
58  54  5   375.3   -11.8   1000
2   0   5   375.5   -6.3    1001
2   8   5   375.3   -6  1000
2   21  5   375.2   -6.1    997
2   37  5   375.3   -6.2    993
2   51  5   375.4   -6.2    1003
5   20  5   376.3   -7.6    1000
5   35  5   376.1   -7.3    1000
5   52  5   375.9   -7.3    1000
6   5   5   376 -7.8    1000
6   23  5   376.1   -8  1002
10  2   5   376.3   -3.3    1003
10  14  5   376.3   -3.1    1003
10  27  5   376.5   -3.4    1003
10  41  5   376.7   -3.7    1006
10  55  5   376.8   -3.9    997
```

I have used the split function previously when there is unique element to each subset of data, however I have nothing unique in this data set from which to split.  Perhaps this function is not what I need?  Any hints appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Your data has 4 unique values in the MIN column. Why doesn't `split()` just work? Please post expected results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `diff` to find the differences between consecutive values and `split` to split the data frame. Assuming your data frame is called `dat`:

```
# create an index for differences > 2
idx <- c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(dat$MIN)) > 2))

# split the data frame
split(dat, idx)
```

The result (a list of 4 data frames):

```
$`0`
   MIN SEC PT  CO2R  CO2D  PAR
1  58  10  5 375.7 -11.6 1002
2  58  20  5 375.4 -11.6 1001
3  58  33  5 375.2 -11.6 1001
4  58  43  5 375.2 -11.5 1000
5  58  54  5 375.3 -11.8 1000

$`1`
   MIN SEC PT  CO2R CO2D  PAR
6    2   0  5 375.5 -6.3 1001
7    2   8  5 375.3 -6.0 1000
8    2  21  5 375.2 -6.1  997
9    2  37  5 375.3 -6.2  993
10   2  51  5 375.4 -6.2 1003

$`2`
   MIN SEC PT  CO2R CO2D  PAR
11   5  20  5 376.3 -7.6 1000
12   5  35  5 376.1 -7.3 1000
13   5  52  5 375.9 -7.3 1000
14   6   5  5 376.0 -7.8 1000
15   6  23  5 376.1 -8.0 1002

$`3`
   MIN SEC PT  CO2R CO2D  PAR
16  10   2  5 376.3 -3.3 1003
17  10  14  5 376.3 -3.1 1003
18  10  27  5 376.5 -3.4 1003
19  10  41  5 376.7 -3.7 1006
20  10  55  5 376.8 -3.9  997
```

Comment: +1. I was thinking along the same lines. Not clear what the OP would want to do in cases where a split might result in a range that is more than 2 apart. For example, replace the current dat$MIN with `c(58, 59, 59, 60, 60, 61, 62, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)`. The first group will contain 58 to 62, but I'm not sure if that's want they would want.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Agreed, the question is rather unclear. If the OP would clarify what to do in these cases, I would change the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses.  Yes I should have been clearer, apologies.  I am using a machine to take manual measurements and when collecting the data it simply applies a 1 to each measurement.  Generally I take 5 measurements and use the mean, however this is a huge data set with many other people using it and sometimes 6 7 or 8 manual measurements are taken.  The only way I can think to split the data set is by separating it by minutes, as it takes about 3 minutes between measurements, and hence get the grouping required for analysis.  Thanks again

Comment: Just to add, there should never be a range of minutes greater than 2 for one complete measurement in which I take the mean, so I am confident that a a difference greater than 2 means a new subset of data.